# Quasitriangular structure for infinitely dimensional Drinfeld double?

Tags: abstract-algebra, hopf-algebras, quantum-groups, braidings

It is well known that the Drinfeld double $D(H)=H^{*op}\otimes H$ of an Hopf algebra $H$ admits a quasitriangular structure. When $H$ is finitely dimensional, the $R$-matrix can be given by
$$R=\sum e^i\otimes e_i$$
where $\{e_i\}$ and $\{e^i\}$ are dual basis for $H$ and $H^*$. But I can hardly find any construction of the $R$-matrix for the infinitely dimensional case. My question is:

> How to define a quasitriangular structure for infinitely dimensional Drinfeld double?

Do I just imitate the finitely dimensional case or it is not even true?

Comment: "The infinitely dimensional Drinfeld double" associated to $H$ is built in some tensor category. Which is this tensor category? So which is the meaning of $\otimes$, and of the dual map $H\to H^*$?